# Editing routes in beforeEach fails because callback passes in invalid routes as to and from parameters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm working on a mobile frontend with Vue. I'd like to dynamically change route transitions to slide left or right depending on the current tab index.

I set up a transition component in my App.js which switches the transition based off the route like this:

```html
<transition :name="$route.meta.transition" mode="out-in">
```

So, to achieve what I want, I thought I could set up a beforeEach hook on each route change, and then modify the current route.meta.transition, and the .meta.transition of the route I'm navigating to.

Here are the route definitions:

```js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/routines',
      name: 'routines',
      component: () => import('../views/Routines/IndexView.vue'),
      meta: { transition: 'slide-right', index: 0 }
    },
    {
      path: '/routines/create',
      name: '/routines/create',
      component: () => import('../views/Routines/CreateView.vue'),
      meta: { transition: 'zoom-in', index: 0 }
    },
    {
      path: '/routines/:id',
      name: '/routines/id',
      component: () => import('../views/Routines/RoutineView.vue'),
      meta: { transition: 'zoom-in', index: 0 }
    },
    {
      path: '/log',
      name: 'log',
      component: () => import('../views/LogView.vue'),
      meta: { transition: 'slide-right', index: 1 }
    },
    {
      path: '/progress',
      name: 'progress',
      component: () => import('../views/ProgressView.vue'),
      meta: { transition: 'slide-right', index: 2 }
    },
    {
      path: '/settings',
      name: 'settings',
      component: () => import('../views/SettingsView.vue'),
      meta: { transition: 'slide-right', index: 3 }
    }
  ]
})
```

And this is the hook I'm setting up to replace the `to` and `from` routes with modified routes with the appropriate string:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log(to, from)
  if (to.meta.index < from.meta.index) {
    console.log({...to, meta: {...to.meta, transition: 'slide-left'}})
    router.addRoute({...to, meta: {...to.meta, transition: 'slide-left'}})
    console.log({...from, meta: {...from.meta, transition: 'slide-left'}})
    router.addRoute({...from, meta: {...from.meta, transition: 'slide-left'}})
  }
  next()
})
```

However, it appears that the `to` and `from` parameters don't have the component keys I defined earlier, so when I replace the routes with `addRoute` by navigating away and then navigate back, I get this error: `Error: Invalid route component`

Confirmation that the `to` and `from` objects are invalid routes:

[image]

How can I solve this issue to achieve a dynamic sliding behavior? I think this hook strategy makes sense. In the future, I'd like to add some more logic to let my child pages zoom in and out when you navigate between a parent and child page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `router.addRoute()`, you can update the route meta directly from the router hook. The [Vue Router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html#route-based-dynamic-transition) suggest using the `afterEach()` hook:

```js
// router.js
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  to.meta.transition = to.meta.index < from.meta.index ? 'slide-right' : 'slide-left'
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-router-transitions?file=src%2Frouter.js)